# Is there a battery cycle counter app?

Tags: battery, battery-life

I have an HTC One M7 (4.4.2), and the battery is starting to deteriorate. It may be that I have some misbehaving apps, but I'd be curious to find out the number of charge cycles my device has used since purchased (like you can do on a laptop).

Is there an app out there that will do this?

My device is rooted.

Comment: Apple's iOS can display cycle count, and many laptops can too.  But I'm not sure that your hardware, your kernel, or your (stock) OS can display cycle count.  Maybe they don't even track it.  The Linux kernel can display cycle count on certain laptops; but I suspect that it probably gets this information provided to it by ACPI.  My Google searching reveals that ACPI is normally not present on ARM-based cellphones or tablets.

Comment: Workaround: When you buy a new battery or new phone, install a cycle-count tracker app. Try [Charge Cycle Battery Stats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.cerebrum.ChargeCycleCounter) (freeware, from Cerebrum Development), but read the instructions in the Google Play app description first.